# Call Tree in Intelllij

Tags: java, methods, intellij-idea, callstack

I want to see method call tree in Intellij. I know we can do it using Ctrl+ Alt+ H, but I am looking for a graphical output similar to the UML diagram. How can we do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the [Code Explorer plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=&pluginId=3739&offset=30&max=15) but be aware that it is quite old. But I tried it out and it seems to be working OK with IntelliJ 12 (some bugs are there).

[image]

Comment: It seems this plugins does not work with Intellij 14.1.4 (141.1532)